# Can't Dist-Upgrade 16.04.2LTS

Tags: apt, updates

I can't get my server to successfully run a dist-upgrade. I keep getting hung up at "update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-83-generic.

It can reboot and everything seems fine otherwise, I just can't get the update to go through.

```
user@server:~$ sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  linux-headers-4.4.0-83 linux-headers-4.4.0-83-generic linux-image-4.4.0-83-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-83-generic
The following packages will be upgraded:
  linux-generic linux-headers-generic linux-image-generic
3 upgraded, 4 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 68.6 MB of archives.
After this operation, 297 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
<<Gets removed because I don't have the rep>>
headers-generic amd64 4.4.0.83.89 [2,260 B]
Fetched 68.6 MB in 34s (1,960 kB/s)
Selecting previously unselected package linux-image-4.4.0-83-generic.
(Reading database ... 62521 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../linux-image-4.4.0-83-generic_4.4.0-83.106_amd64.deb ...
Done.
Unpacking linux-image-4.4.0-83-generic (4.4.0-83.106) ...
Selecting previously unselected package linux-image-extra-4.4.0-83-generic.
Preparing to unpack .../linux-image-extra-4.4.0-83-generic_4.4.0-83.106_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-image-extra-4.4.0-83-generic (4.4.0-83.106) ...
Preparing to unpack .../linux-generic_4.4.0.83.89_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-generic (4.4.0.83.89) over (4.4.0.62.65) ...
Preparing to unpack .../linux-image-generic_4.4.0.83.89_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-image-generic (4.4.0.83.89) over (4.4.0.62.65) ...
Selecting previously unselected package linux-headers-4.4.0-83.
Preparing to unpack .../linux-headers-4.4.0-83_4.4.0-83.106_all.deb ...
Unpacking linux-headers-4.4.0-83 (4.4.0-83.106) ...
Selecting previously unselected package linux-headers-4.4.0-83-generic.
Preparing to unpack .../linux-headers-4.4.0-83-generic_4.4.0-83.106_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-headers-4.4.0-83-generic (4.4.0-83.106) ...
Preparing to unpack .../linux-headers-generic_4.4.0.83.89_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-headers-generic (4.4.0.83.89) over (4.4.0.62.65) ...
Setting up linux-image-4.4.0-83-generic (4.4.0-83.106) ...
Running depmod.
update-initramfs: deferring update (hook will be called later)
Examining /etc/kernel/postinst.d.
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 4.4.0-83-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-83-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 4.4.0-83-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-83-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-83-generic
```

Comment: This appears to have sorted itself out. I'm not sure if the updates themselves were updated to fix an issue  or what the case may be but I recently gave it another shot without any new steps and it went through fine.